# Portability vs Platform Independent

Tags: comparison, cross-platform, portability

Can someone explain me difference of these? If the program is platform independent doesn't it make it portable too and the opposite?

Comment: [Portable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application). [Platform independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_independent#Platform-independent_software). It should be pretty clear from carefully reading the definitions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the phrases "Java is platform independent" and "Java is portable"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300525/what-is-the-difference-between-the-phrases-java-is-platform-independent-and-j)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Platform independent means, these programs can run in "nearly" all operating systems. Doesn't need to be all, but at least MS, Linux and Mac will be fine to use this word.

And, lets dig out the facts behind the word "platform independent".

NOTE: The following sentences are my opinions. If anyone read, couldn't understand the logic behind or doesn't like, just can press on buttons <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to close. I noted these because Java programmers getting seriously mad when they face this sentences. But it is always open for discussion.
Check please: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform-independent_model

Ok don't break the topic and turn back.

1. Actually and logically, any program needs a platform installer can't be considered as platform independent. For example, if I **can't** run Java executables without downloading and installing java runtime packages services etc...  So how we can say that it is platform independent. If we can say, so nearly 80% of the windows executables are also platform independent since you can run them with virtual machines or WINE on Linux etc. And sure, if Java is platform independent, PHP, ASP, Perl, Python, Ruby etc. all scripting languages are also platform independent!?  Aah, sure not...
   Hope you got the logic.
2. But what we can do is, we can compile our (own) softwares for many different OS's. So our software will be "cross platform"
3. What can be platform independent in real manner is
   (as I wrote in top, my opinions)
   Uncompiled assembly, C etc codes...

And when it comes to portable, this is something else. For example, the word "portable software" under "windows" operating system means;

- Doesn't use registry or Appdata folder for its files or settings.
- Works under its own folder, all files needed for it is located under it's own folder.
- Also saves it's settings to a file (ini etc) under it's own folder.

And if we go a bit further in meaning, even mustn't rely on specific hardware/software brand, model or unusual mode (like "x" brand screen card, "y" resolution, "z" release of DirectX etc.).  But actually you can just ignore the last detail since this criteria is not mature yet to be accepted by all.

Comment: Make up your mind. Either they are facts or they are just your opinions. A lot of baseless assertions here. -1