# What is the difference between the phrases "Java is platform independent" and "Java is portable"?

Tags: java

I am new to java . When i was studying java programming I came to these two terms many times which looked similar and had similar meaning. I searched about it in many sites but i couldn't find the best difference i was looking for. Can anyone clarify this to me is it same or different ??

Comment: the word meaning is different .. but in java these two terms refer to the same thing most of the time

Comment: I don't think that the link you quote is a very good discussion of these terms. Above all, there is no effort at defining what these terms (frequently used in sales pitch) should mean.

Comment: *portablity* - Is more general and states - *The program can run on any other machine with the same or different architecture / OS*. *Platform independence* - is less general and not inclusive. *The program can run on any machine with a different architecture.*

Comment: Define "Java" to mean "the Java language", as defined by the Language Specification. Then "Java" is *platform independent* as there is nothing in the language that inhibits it being implemented on any of common computers. I (!) prefer to apply the term "portable" to programs; thus "Java (programs) are portable" as the language is defined in such a way that execution semantics remain the same across platforms where Java is available (*if the programmer doesn't err*); and since the language is also defined as compiled byte code, the portability extends to compiled code as well.

Comment: @TheLostMind It would be worthwile to have a better definition of these terms than in that link, which isn't a satisfactory explanation at all.

Comment: @laune - I agree.. Voted to *reopen*.

Comment: @alfasin I just convinced TheLostMind to vote for reopen. See comments

Comment: "Aren't all languages defined to be *platform independend*?" Many are, but a famous counterexample is PL/I, which was *defined* to permit direct use of certain OS (OS/360) features.

Comment: @laune Agreed, the answer at that link is very poor quality, 99% opinion and rant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original meaning of 'portable' was 'costs less to convert to a new platform than it does to rewrite for the new platform'. As languages evolved and vendor lock-ins reduced, it has since morphed to mean several things including binary compatibility and source-code compatibility.

'Platform-independent' means that there is nothing in the system or its specification that is inherently bound to a single platform.

They're related, but not the same thing.

Comment: Code can also be platform independent (and it has to be in order to be easily portable). I'd say that they are the same thing.

Comment: @Torben *Non sequitur*

Answer (score -1):

**portability** stands for the way how you package and ship your Java code aka Java Application.

**Platform independent** stands for the way it is developed in such a way that the same can be implemented or emulated in any types of platforms.

Happy Coding !